# Blazor WASM table sorting issue

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

This one's got me scratching my head. I have a table with sorting functionality, and one of the columns in this table is a checkbox bound to that row's entity.

However, when I click to sort on a column, the entity's checkbox doesn't sort with the rest of the row's entries. It will sort other columns that have inputs in their respective `td`s however.

I threw up a quick [repo here](https://github.com/mtranchi/SOSortTable) if you'd like to check out this behavior. It's the standard Blazor WASM template; I used the "Forecasts" page to demonstrate the issue. Check one of the checkboxes, then hit the sort button a couple of times to see it.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. Needed to use `@bind`, not `@bind-value`. Odd though that `@bind-value` works on other inputs though.